# $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData not working

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid  . But I am not able to paint the data from json using  $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData method.. Only headers are displayed.Data is not painted in UI.

Find the code below

```
myApp.controller("getProfitabilityDetailsController", function($scope, $http) {
    var columnDefs = [
                    {headerName: 'quantity',field: 'quantity',  width: 150},
                    {headerName: 'finyear',field: 'finyear',  width: 150}
                    ];
    $scope.gridOptions = {
                            columnDefs: columnDefs
                        };
    $http.get("partials/profitability/mock/profitability_details.json")
    .then(function(result){
                        $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(result.data.response);
                        });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

A classic error to check when using ag-grid :

Does the div containing the ag-grid directive has a raw height specified (raw = in px) or any parent dom element. If not add a style="height:500px" for instance.

Otherwise i need to see the html you're using and the format of your json file.

Comment: I feel like a dummy but this worked for me, thank you!

Comment: Same here it's not working. I am struggling. The below is html code<div class="row" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                              <div ag-grid="gridOptions" style="height: 100%" class="ag-blue"></div>
                            </div>
                          </div>

Answer (score 2):

try this instead:

```
 $http.get("partials/profitability/mock/profitability_details.json")
    .then(function(result){
         $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(result.data);
    });
```

Looks like you had an extra property name on return

Comment: U used to have $scope.tableName.rowData = response; and then used an empty setter method. Somewhy in one case this combination refused to work, and your option did it well. Thx